# More vertex data or more expensive shader?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, gpu

I can either:

upload vertices to the buffer and do a several extra instructions, nothing very expensive, a couple vec4 creations, additions, and a single vec4 x mat4 mulpltication.

upload triple the amount of vertices to the buffer and do not require the extra math.

In both cases, the same amount of vertices are sent to the shader. It's just the buffer size that will vary, because the first method uses an indexing/instancing trick.

Obviously the first case is faster for buffer uploading but what about drawing?which would likely be faster on most machines?

Although I'm using opengl this question applies to directx too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a good answer based on the information you provide. It depends on at least the following things:

- number of vertices and other data (if you are CPU-GPU bandwidth bound)
- amount of work you already do in vertex shader (if GPU is vertex processing bound)
- amount of work in pixel shader (if GPU is pixel processing bound)
- control flow in vertex shader (if the additional work you need to do requires dynamic branches or other expensive stuff)

Generally I believe rendering is rarely ALU bound in the vertex shader, so it might be OK to do the calculations, but there's no way to know without profiling. Try both and measure the GPU times (e.g. with Nvidia NSight or AMD PerfStudio) to get the actual answer. Also remember to repeat the profiling after you make other changes to the rendering pipeline, since the above factor may have caused the bottleneck to shift.